# Solving a Query on SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql, subquery

need some help on solving this query.
I want to get projects that had no change in their team (i.e. because project0002 has two different project managers it must not appear on the result of the query)

Can you help me ?

```
CREATE TABLE sprintMembers (
  userID                 NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL, 
  sprintNumber           NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL, 
  sprintProjectCode      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  memberRole                   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 

  PRIMARY KEY (userID, sprintNumber, sprintProjectCode));

INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (4,1,'PROJ0001', 'Project Manager');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (5,1,'PROJ0001', 'Product Owner');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (6,1,'PROJ0001', 'Scrum Master');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (4,1,'PROJ0002', 'Project Manager');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (3,2,'PROJ0002', 'Project Manager');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (4,3,'PROJ0002', 'Project Manager');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (5,1,'PROJ0002', 'Product Owner');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (5,2,'PROJ0002', 'Product Owner');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (7,1,'PROJ0002', 'Team Member');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (7,2,'PROJ0002', 'Team Member');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (4,1,'PROJ0003', 'Project Manager');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (4,2,'PROJ0003', 'Project Manager');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (5,1,'PROJ0003', 'Product Owner');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (5,2,'PROJ0003', 'Product Owner');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (7,1,'PROJ0003', 'Scrum Master');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (7,2,'PROJ0003', 'Scrum Master');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (6,1,'PROJ0003', 'Team Member');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (6,2,'PROJ0003', 'Team Member');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (8,1,'PROJ0004', 'Project Manager');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (8,2,'PROJ0004', 'Project Manager');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (8,3,'PROJ0004', 'Project Manager');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (9,1,'PROJ0004', 'Product Owner');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (9,2,'PROJ0004', 'Product Owner');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (9,3,'PROJ0004', 'Product Owner');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (10,1,'PROJ0004', 'Scrum Master');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (10,2,'PROJ0004', 'Scrum Master');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (10,3,'PROJ0004', 'Scrum Master');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (6,1,'PROJ0004', 'Team Member');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (6,2,'PROJ0004', 'Team Member');
INSERT INTO sprintMembers VALUES (6,3,'PROJ0004', 'Team Member');
```

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can aggregate and count distinct `userId`

```
select sprintProjectCode
from sprintMembers
group by sprintProjectCode
having Count(distinct case when memberRole='project manager' then userid end)=1
```

Result:

```
PROJ0001
PROJ0003
PROJ0004
```

**Edit**

Another approach applying to all member role values

```
with groups as (
    select sprintProjectCode, Count(*) cnt
    from sprintMembers
    group by sprintProjectCode, userid, memberrole
)
select sprintProjectCode
from groups
group by sprintProjectCode
having Min(cnt) = Max(cnt)
```

Comment: is that another way to obtain the result ? because I must not specify the memberRole because it may be a generic member role. the rule is that the team (project manager, scrum master, product owner and team member) has always the same userids. if one of them change then the project must be excluded from the result.

Comment: @JoanaPinheiro OK it appears I didn't quite understand, I have edited my answer with an alternative query, does that work for you?

Comment: it worked ! thank you very much for your help !